# Sql Statement Execution Taking a Long Time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a sql statement that has been running fine for more than 6 months and recently it started taking an exorbitant time to execute.

`DMIRecord` contains 15,950 rows and `InHouse_CSV_Backup` has 149,226 rows. I set up an index on both `MERSMin` and `MERSNUMBER` on their respective tables and rebuilt the existing indexes but it has not helped.

I have another query that does the same thing but `DMIRecord` is a different source table called 'MERSRecord' and contains 28,841 rows and it runs fine. This query runs in 1 second and returns 2,048 rows

Can anyone give me some things to look at to resolve the problem. The last time I ran the below query it took 1 hour and 48 minutes to return 15,435 rows.

I know the join is not ideal but that is what we have to work with. There is nothing else that can connect these to externally imported data sources.

```
SELECT m.*
FROM    [MERSReconciliation].[DMIRecord] m
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[InHouse_CSV_Backup] b ON CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(m.[MERSMin])) AS VARCHAR(31)) = REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(b.[MERSNUMBER)),
                                                              '-', '')
WHERE ( ( m.[Resolved] IS NULL
            OR m.[Resolved] = 0
          )
          AND ( m.[Ignore Always] IS NULL
                OR m.[Ignore Always] = 0
              )
          AND ( m.[Ignore] IS NULL
                OR m.[Ignore] = 0
              )
          AND ( m.[Processed] IS NULL
                OR m.[Processed] = 0
              )
        )
        AND b.[MERSNUMBER] IS NULL
```

Sample Data for Join DMIRecord

```
100113800001196174
100113800001155030
100113800001204309
```

Sample Data for Join InHouse_CSV_Backup

```
1001138-0000008482-7
NULL
1001138-0000008479-3
```

Here are the Execution Plans for both Bad and Good

Bad: DMIRecords
[image]

Good: MERSRecord
[image]

I added `*` to the query to simplify the statement for posting. All needed columns are defined in the actual statement.

```
USE [ExtraNet]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [MERSReconciliation].[DMIRecord]    Script Date: 1/29/2015 5:01:35 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [MERSReconciliation].[DMIRecord](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClientNo] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [DetailRecordCtlNo] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [ReportingEntityNo] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [OrganizationName] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [MERSOrgId] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [LienPriorityCode] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [RealEstateSecurityCode] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [FHACaseNo] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [InvestLoanNo] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [MERSMin] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [LoanDate] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [OrigMtgAmt] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [EntityTypeQual] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [NameTypeCode] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [MtgrSSNo] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [MtgrLastName] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [MtgrFirstName] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [MtgrMiddleName] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoEntityTypeQual1] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoNameTypeCode1] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoMtgrSSNo1] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerLastName1] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerFirstName1] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerMiddleName1] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoEntityTypeQual2] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoNameTypeCode2] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoMtgrSSNo2] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerLastName2] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerFirstName2] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerMiddleName2] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoEntityTypeQual3] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoNameTypeCode3] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoMtgrSSNo3] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerLastName3] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerFirstName3] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerMiddleName3] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoEntityTypeQual4] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoNameTypeCode4] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoMtgrSSNo4] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerLastName4] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerFirstName4] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerMiddleName4] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoEntityTypeQual5] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoNameTypeCode5] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoMtgrSSNo5] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerLastName5] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerFirstName5] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerMiddleName5] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoEntityTypeQual6] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoNameTypeCode6] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoMtgrSSNo6] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerLastName6] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerFirstName6] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerMiddleName6] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoEntityTypeQual7] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoNameTypeCode7] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoMtgrSSNo7] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerLastName7] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerFirstName7] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerMiddleName7] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoEntityTypeQual8] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoNameTypeCode8] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoMtgrSSNo8] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerLastName8] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerFirstName8] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerMiddleName8] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoEntityTypeQual9] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoNameTypeCode9] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoMtgrSSNo9] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerLastName9] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerFirstName9] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerMiddleName9] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoEntityTypeQual10] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoNameTypeCode10] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoMtgrSSNo10] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerLastName10] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerFirstName10] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [CoborrowerMiddleName10] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [NuStreetNo] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [NuStreetName] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [NuStreetDir] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [NuCityName] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [NuStateAbbr] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [NuPropZip] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [NuPropSuffix] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [NuPropUnitNo] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [County] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [MERsMOMflag] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [PoolNo] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [MERsFundingDate] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [MERsOrigOrgId] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [OrigNoteHldNm] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [MinStatCd] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [MERsPropertyPresOrgId] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [InvMERsOrgId] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [SecuritizationName] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [PropertyUnitType] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [DateAssignFrMERs] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [MERsStatusReasonCode] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [OccupancyStatus] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [AgencyNbr] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [SubservicingMERsOrgId] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [Assignee] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [AssigneeAddressInfo] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [AssigneeCity] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [AssigneeState] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [AssigneeZipCode] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [Assignor] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [Resolved] [bit] NULL,
    [Ignore Always] [bit] NULL,
    [Ignore] [bit] NULL,
    [Processed] [bit] NULL,
    [ImportedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ImportedBy] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [UpdatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [UpdatedBy] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [F2FResolved] [bit] NULL,
    [F2FIgnore Always] [bit] NULL,
    [F2FIgnore] [bit] NULL,
    [F2FProcessed] [bit] NULL,
    [Comment] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [F2FComment] [varchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DMIRecord] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

USE [ExtraNet]
GO

    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[InHouse_CSV_Backup]    Script Date: 1/29/2015 5:01:11 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    SET ANSI_PADDING ON
    GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InHouse_CSV_Backup](
        [Loan_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [LOANNUMBER] [float] NULL,
        [LOANNUMBE1] [float] NULL,
        [MERSNUMBER] [nvarchar](31) NULL,
        [LEADID] [float] NULL,
        [CALCDATELE] [datetime] NULL,
        [PBFIRSTNAM] [nvarchar](26) NULL,
        [PBLASTNAME] [nvarchar](36) NULL,
        [PBSOCIALSE] [nvarchar](51) NULL,
        [PCFIRSTNAM] [nvarchar](26) NULL,
        [PCLASTNAME] [nvarchar](36) NULL,
        [PBVOICE] [nvarchar](13) NULL,
        [PBWORKNUMB] [nvarchar](13) NULL,
        [LOANSTATUS] [nvarchar](21) NULL,
        [StatusDate] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [StatusDays] [float] NULL,
        [PBCREDITSC] [float] NULL,
        [PCCREDITSC] [float] NULL,
        [BDETOTAL11] [float] NULL,
        [BDETOTAL21] [float] NULL,
        [BDETOTAL10] [float] NULL,
        [LTV] [float] NULL,
        [COMBINEDLT] [float] NULL,
        [HOUSINGRAT] [float] NULL,
        [DEBTRATIO] [float] NULL,
        [PBAGE] [float] NULL,
        [PCAGE] [float] NULL,
        [BDEYEARSAT] [float] NULL,
        [BDEYEARSA1] [float] NULL,
        [INVESTOR] [nvarchar](51) NULL,
        [PRODUCTCOD] [nvarchar](21) NULL,
        [PROGRAMNAM] [nvarchar](51) NULL,
        [PROGRAMCAT] [nvarchar](16) NULL,
        [LOANPURPOS] [nvarchar](26) NULL,
        [DOCUMENTAT] [nvarchar](21) NULL,
        [SPPURPOSEO] [nvarchar](51) NULL,
        [LIENPOSITI] [nvarchar](16) NULL,
        [FUNDINGTYP] [nvarchar](16) NULL,
        [SPOCCUPANC] [nvarchar](26) NULL,
        [LOANTYPE] [nvarchar](16) NULL,
        [SPPROPERTY] [nvarchar](26) NULL,
        [RATE] [float] NULL,
        [LOANTERM] [float] NULL,
        [LOANAMOUNT] [float] NULL,
        [LBRANCHNUM] [nvarchar](11) NULL,
        [LOEMPLOYEE] [nvarchar](16) NULL,
        [LOFIRSTNAM] [nvarchar](26) NULL,
        [LOLASTNAME] [nvarchar](36) NULL,
        [LPFIRSTNAM] [nvarchar](26) NULL,
        [LPLASTNAME] [nvarchar](36) NULL,
        [LUFIRSTNAM] [nvarchar](26) NULL,
        [LULASTNAME] [nvarchar](36) NULL,
        [LEADSOURCE] [nvarchar](31) NULL,
        [REFERRALSO] [nvarchar](51) NULL,
        [BROKERCOMP] [float] NULL,
        [BRCOMPANYN] [nvarchar](51) NULL,
        [SELLERREAL] [float] NULL,
        [SACOMPANYN] [nvarchar](51) NULL,
        [SellerAgenPhone] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [SABRANCHNA] [nvarchar](26) NULL,
        [SAFIRSTNAM] [nvarchar](26) NULL,
        [SALASTNAME] [nvarchar](36) NULL,
        [ADDRESS] [nvarchar](36) NULL,
        [SPCITY] [nvarchar](26) NULL,
        [SPSTATE] [nvarchar](3) NULL,
        [SPZIP] [nvarchar](11) NULL,
        [SPCOUNTY] [nvarchar](21) NULL,
        [PBPAADDRES] [nvarchar](36) NULL,
        [PBPACITY] [nvarchar](26) NULL,
        [PBPASTATE] [nvarchar](3) NULL,
        [PBPAZIP] [nvarchar](11) NULL,
        [CALCDATEPR] [datetime] NULL,
        [CALCDATENO] [datetime] NULL,
        [CALCDATEON] [datetime] NULL,
        [CALCDATEP1] [datetime] NULL,
        [CALCDATEAP] [datetime] NULL,
        [CALCDATEP2] [datetime] NULL,
        [CALCDATESU] [datetime] NULL,
        [CALCDATEA1] [datetime] NULL,
        [CALCDATEA2] [datetime] NULL,
        [CALCDATEA3] [datetime] NULL,
        [CLoanFunded] [datetime] NULL,
        [AppraisalReceived] [datetime] NULL,
        [CALCDATEES] [datetime] NULL,
        [SHIPPED] [datetime] NULL,
        [FIRSTPAYME] [datetime] NULL,
        [LOCKDATE] [datetime] NULL,
        [LOCKEXPIRE] [datetime] NULL,
        [CALCDATEDO] [datetime] NULL,
        [CALCDATED1] [datetime] NULL,
        [CALCDATED2] [datetime] NULL,
        [CALCDATEIN] [datetime] NULL,
        [CALCDATEFU] [datetime] NULL,
        [CLOSEDATE] [datetime] NULL,
        [CANCELDATE] [datetime] NULL,
        [CALCDATERE] [datetime] NULL,
        [CALCDATEI1] [datetime] NULL,
        [MONTHLYLOA] [float] NULL,
        [TOTALMONTH] [float] NULL,
        [ProductID] [float] NULL,
        [CPI] [char](10) NULL,
        [BrokeredOut] [datetime] NULL,
        [Commitment] [varchar](25) NULL,
        [Pool] [varchar](25) NULL,
        [Points801] [float] NULL,
        [Points802] [float] NULL,
        [ConfirmedPrice] [float] NULL,
        [InvPrice] [float] NULL,
        [InvLockDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [Units] [float] NULL,
        [InvID] [float] NULL,
        [Committed_Product] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [FloodZone] [char](10) NULL,
        [ModBack] [datetime] NULL,
        [CommSplitID] [char](10) NULL,
        [CommissionSplit] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [PropertyClass] [varchar](25) NULL,
        [PUDType] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [InvBase] [float] NULL,
        [LockConfBase] [float] NULL,
        [DeedReceivedDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [TitleReceivedDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [InvestorClearedDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [InvestorDeniedDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [InvestorSuspendedDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [FHACaseNum] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [DeniedDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [LockCancelled] [datetime] NULL,
        [UWRecievedDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [UWSuspended] [datetime] NULL,
        [ForwardCancelled] [datetime] NULL,
        [LeadB2B] [datetime] NULL,
        [ServicingBegin] [datetime] NULL,
        [ServicingEnd] [datetime] NULL,
        [MICertNum] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [WareHouseLine] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [FirstCreditScoreDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [DuplicateFlag] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [MinCreditScore] [nchar](10) NULL,
        [NMLS_ID] [nchar](10) NULL,
        [PQ_ApprovedDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [CompletedDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [PQ_DeniedDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [PQ_WithdrawnDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [LeadInactiveDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [LoanOriginatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [IncometeAppDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [HOEPAStatus] [nchar](10) NULL,
        [FinanceMethod] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [IOMonths] [nchar](10) NULL,
        [MI_Type] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [MI_Activated] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [MI_ExpireDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [Fee902] [money] NULL,
        [Fee1002] [money] NULL,
        [HOEPA] [nchar](10) NULL,
        [RequiredCreditScore] [nchar](10) NULL,
        [ApprovedWithdrawn] [datetime] NULL,
        [Withdrawn] [datetime] NULL,
        [BranchDenied] [datetime] NULL,
        [PQSubmitted] [datetime] NULL,
        [Prepay] [nchar](10) NULL,
        [CountyCD] [varchar](3) NULL,
        [StateCD] [varchar](2) NULL,
        [IsTestLoan] [bit] NULL,
        [ReqClose_Dt] [date] NULL,
        [LockReneg_Dt] [date] NULL,
        [PTD_Cond_Count] [int] NULL,
        [AdminFee] [varchar](3) NULL,
        [PricingTier] [varchar](12) NULL,
        [Borr_MidName] [nvarchar](36) NULL,
        [CoBorr2_FirstName] [nvarchar](26) NULL,
        [CoBorr2_MidName] [nvarchar](36) NULL,
        [CoBorr2_LastName] [nvarchar](36) NULL,
        [CoBorr2_SSN] [varchar](15) NULL,
        [CoBorr2_Address] [nvarchar](36) NULL,
        [CoBorr2_City] [nvarchar](26) NULL,
        [CoBorr2_State] [varchar](2) NULL,
        [CoBorr2_ZIP] [varchar](10) NULL,
        [CoBorr2_CredScore] [int] NULL,
        [CoBorr3_FirstName] [nvarchar](26) NULL,
        [CoBorr3_MidName] [nvarchar](36) NULL,
        [CoBorr3_LastName] [nvarchar](36) NULL,
        [CoBorr3_SSN] [varchar](15) NULL,
        [CoBorr3_Address] [nvarchar](36) NULL,
        [CoBorr3_City] [nvarchar](26) NULL,
        [CoBorr3_State] [varchar](2) NULL,
        [CoBorr3_ZIP] [varchar](10) NULL,
        [CoBorr3_CredScore] [int] NULL,
        [Created_Dt] [datetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_InHouse_CSV_Backup_Created_Dt]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
        [LastUpdated_Dt] [datetime] NULL,
        [IntentProceed_Dt] [date] NULL,
        [ClearClose_Dt] [date] NULL,
        [SellerRealtor_ID] [int] NULL,
        [BuyerRealtor_ID] [int] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_InHouse_CSV_Backup] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        [Loan_ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO

    SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
    GO
```

I ran the tuning advisor and it didn't suggest anything to improve it.

Interesting thing to note. I went back to the original SQL 2008 server that hosted these before and both statements execute in under 3 seconds. Both execution plans are identical. On the SQL 2012 Server only the MERSRecord query's execution plan is the same. All three match the one listed above. Only DMIRecords on the SQL 2012 server is different. Possible Bug?

1/30/2012
Update showing solution from my question on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90600/execution-plans-differ-for-the-same-sql-statement)
add OPTION (HASH JOIN) to the end of the statement forcing a hash join. Adding this resulted in the problem query executing in 1 second and returning the proper result set.

Comment: The problem is with your `non-sargable` `join` condition. Could you provide some sample data and expected results?

Comment: Might be worth comparing the actual execution plans of the good and bad query and looking for differences. Don't worry if you don't understand what it says, if you can find a difference that might help someone to help you :)

Comment: can you give sample rows with your database. maybe we can help boost your query.

Comment: Probably wouldn't hurt for you to post a screenshot of your execution plan.

Comment: Please also post schema for `TableA` and `TableB`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `CTE` to clean your data. Using functions in the `JOIN` condition will prevent the use of index.

```
;WITH CteTableA AS(
    SELECT      
        TrimmedCol1 = CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(m.[COL1])) AS VARCHAR(31)),
        Resolved = ISNULL(Resolved, 0),
        [Ignore Always] = ISNULL([Ignore Always], 0),
        Ignore = ISNULL(Ignore, 0),
        Processed = ISNULL(Processed, 0)        
    FROM TableA
)
,CteTableB AS(
    SELECT
        *,
        TrimmedCol3 = REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(b.[COL3])),'-', '')
    FROM TableB
)
SELECT
    a.*
FROM CteTableA a
LEFT JOIN CteTableB b
    ON b.TrimmedCol3 = a.TrimmedCol1
WHERE
    a.Resolved = 0
    AND a.[Ignore Always] = 0
    AND a.Ignore = 0
    AND a.Processed = 0
    AND b.ACCOUNTNUMBER IS NULL
```

## EDIT:

Try cleaning up the data and insert it in a temp table. Then add necessary index.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTableA(
    TrimmedCol1     VARCHAR(31),
    Resolved        BIT,
    [Ignore Always] BIT,
    Ignore          BIT,
    Processed       BIT
    -- Other columns you might need
)
CREATE TABLE #TempTableB(
    TrimmedCol3 VARCHAR(31),
    MERSNUMBER  NVARCHAR(31) NULL
    -- Other columns you might need
)
INSERT INTO #TempTableA
    SELECT      
        TrimmedCol1 = CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(m.[COL1])) AS VARCHAR(31)),
        Resolved = ISNULL(Resolved, 0),
        [Ignore Always] = ISNULL([Ignore Always], 0),
        Ignore = ISNULL(Ignore, 0),
        Processed = ISNULL(Processed, 0)        
    FROM TableA

INSERT INTO #TempTableB
    SELECT
        TrimmedCol3 = REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(b.[COL3])),'-', ''),
        MERSNUMBER
    FROM TableB

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX #IX_TempTableA ON #TempTableA (TrimmedCol1)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX #IX_TempTableB ON #TempTableB (TrimmedCol3)

SELECT
    a.*
FROM #TempTableA a
LEFT JOIN #TempTableB b
    ON b.TrimmedCol3 = a.TrimmedCol1
WHERE
    a.Resolved = 0
    AND a.[Ignore Always] = 0
    AND a.Ignore = 0
    AND a.Processed = 0
    AND b.MERSNUMBER IS NULL
```

Comment: 12 minutes into this execution and still no results returned. It's doesn't look promising.

Comment: Thanks wewesthemenace I'll give it a try. I'm executing this currently from inline sql in a C# Win app but if it works I'll work around that. But here's the weird thing. The databases were recently moved from a SQL08 to a SQL12 box. I went back to the 08 box and ran the sql and it worked just fine. The execution plan even looks like the good execution plan in the OP. The statement completed with 8 rows in 2 seconds. TableA has 15,950 rows and TableB has 146,717 rows so there's not much difference is data. Thoughts?

Comment: What query? Your original? I'm not really an expert in this but have you tried rebuilding the index and updating statistics? Also, check both configurations and `set options`. Maybe they're different.

Comment: Yes' the original query. I rebuilt all index on both table yesterday but it didn't seem to help. Can you elaborate on " check both configurations and set options" I'm not familiar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69866/discussion-between-wewesthemenace-and-tim).

Comment: Thanks  wewesthemenace this does solve my execution time problem but I still don't understand why the execution plans differ, but that is a problem for another day.

Comment: Update showing solution from my question from http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90600/execution-plans-differ-for-the-same-sql-statement  OPTION (HASH JOIN)